# How to set cursor right to left direction in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox, right-to-left, caret

I have a application that works in Hebrew. And therefore the direction of writing is from right to left.
When I open richtextbox I want the cursor will be in the right direction, ie from right to left.
How do I do this? I want to do it in the "Load" of the richtextbox.

The following code does not do what I want:

```
richTxtRtfText.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```

Thanks in advance

Any word processor do it with pressing Alt+Shift
can I send something likw that to the  RTB?

Answer (score 2):

If your using visual studio and winforms then there is a property for rich text boxes called RightToLeft

```
rtx.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```

Comment: I've had it in the properties of the RTB